# Amazon EC2 - Install Private Key on new instance BEFORE user-data script runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-key

I'm looking for a secure way to install a private key on new instances that can then been utilized by user details scripts. I am **not** looking to use this key for SSHing; instead, I'd like the user-data script to pull an encrypted file and decrypt it using the private key.

Is this possible? I'd like to avoid using something totally AWS-specific for portability, but am open to whatever options are out there.

Comment: How about creating a custom AMI from a snapshot where you've already installed the private key?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that'd be the route I needed to go. Wasn't sure if the user data scripts would run as expected after the fact, but it makes sense that they would. Probably what I'll end up doing unless someone gets creative

Comment: Or how about using IAM Roles for EC2. You could set up and Instance Profile that allows this instance to access a particular S3 bucket, and keep the private key in there? Then the first step in the user-data script would be to use the instance's own credentials to retrieve and install the key.

Comment: I like the idea of that but feel funny about leaving the PK in there. But in the end the PK just ends up on the AMI with the other route. 

Wait, can an EC2 instance determine S3 api keys at runtime (using IAM roles)?

Comment: That's right. [This guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) explains it pretty, but basically the SDKs/command line tools will all pick up the API keys automatically if the instance is configured with IAM roles.

Comment: Putting private keys in S3 guarded by temporary credentials means any authenticated user can read those keys, because all metadata (including credentials) is easily accessible from the instance over HTTP.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. What I was thinking (and ended up doing) was leaving the private key & credentials configured on the AMI, and then using them to read the encrypted payload from the user data script. This has turned out to work great! Will post an official answer here soon

Comment: @DavidWelch what if a user has access to the ami? they can spawn a new instance

Comment: @vimdude yeah, this old dinosaur of a post is inherently flawed. AWS has way better primitives for dealing with this, let alone that there's a ton of orchestration and platform tech (we've moved into kubernetes and love it) that make these things non-issues